# Place buttons into multiple columns android

Tags: android, layout

As they look in the picture: http://es.tinypic.com/r/mug8b8/8

In the month of having a single column, have several with botons
The genre buttons dynamically by a query
The function that generates the buttons:

```
private void createEmpresas() {
    Button b;
    JSONObject json = null;
    int count = 0;
    LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);
    JSONObject jobj = obj_sqlite.get_descripcion_empresas();

    try {
        count = Integer.parseInt(jobj.getString("cont"));
        json = new JSONObject(jobj.getString("json"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("getParams", e.getMessage());
    }

    for (int x = 1; x <= count; x++) {

        try {
            JSONObject json_row = new JSONObject(json.getString("row" + x));

            b = new Button(this);
            b.setText(json_row.getString("descripcion"));
            b.setId(json_row.getInt("empresa"));
            b.setTextSize(10);
            b.setPadding(8, 3, 8, 3);
            b.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
            b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            lm.addView(b);

            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Yipee.." +v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("getParams", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

my xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bg_main"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.php_mysql_sqlite.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="loginOut"
    android:text="@string/btLogOut"
    android:textColor="@color/Red" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="syncSqliteMysql"
    android:text="@string/syn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:onClick="borrarTabla"
    android:text="@string/delTable" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="285dp"
    android:layout_height="330dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks for the help

PS: If you give me negative points, leave a comment of reason, as has happened before and not why

Comment: i suggest you to use listView instead .. it's better..and you get good result ..

Comment: aaah you want something like grid ?

Comment: I saw it as a suggestion on a question @CharefEddineMechalikh

Comment: Can you give me an example? @CharefEddineMechalikh

Answer (score 0):

here are some answers that may help

1-
[In android how do I add buttons into a TableLayout from an array of buttons programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777451/in-android-how-do-i-add-buttons-into-a-tablelayout-from-an-array-of-buttons-prog)

2-
[How do I programmatically add buttons into layout one by one in several lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195056/how-do-i-programmatically-add-buttons-into-layout-one-by-one-in-several-lines)

3-
[Add an array of buttons to a GridView in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775188/add-an-array-of-buttons-to-a-gridview-in-an-android-application)